# fallo en la compilación npm start

Tags: npm

[[![![Error de compilacion en el comando aplicado npx cretae-react-app][1]][1]"][2]][2]

Sufro un error que no descubro como solucionar al aplicar el comando npx create-react-app "nombredelarchivo" el error es el indicado en la imagen
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h9Sp.png

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola DarioFerrer bienvenido, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta elimina la imagen, y agrega tu código y el mensaje de error como texto.
Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!